# Given n distinct numbers show that the second smallest element can be found in n + lg n - 2 comparisons in the worst case

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

This is a question from Introduction to Algorithms by CLRS (Exercise 9-1-1).

The approach I thought of is

- compare the first two numbers, assign the lower number min and the bigger one to next_min
- loop through numbers 3 - n,
  if the number is lower than min, set min to that number.
  else if the number if lower than next_min set next_min to that number

If this is the optimal solution how can I prove the number of comparisons is n + lg n - 2.

Comment: Your solution gives something like $2n$ (minus a small constant). There is a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm with $n + \lceil \lg n \rceil -2$ comparisons uses ["tournament" (lecture note from utdallas)](https://www.utdallas.edu/~chandra/documents/6363/lbd.pdf).

- To form a tournament tree: Compare $A[2i−1]$ with $A[2i]$ for $i = 1$
  to $n$. We compare the "winners" in pairs and so on.
- Collect all the keys that *directly* lost to the maximum and compute their maximum. That is, the second largest key.

The time complexity is $(n-1) + (\lceil \lg n \rceil - 1) = n + \lceil \lg n \rceil -2$.

---

Actually, the lower bound for "finding the second largest/smallest element" is $n + \lceil \lg n \rceil -2$, which can be proved by adversary argument (at the end of the lecture above).

Comment: The file says the height of the tree is $\lceil{\log_{2} n}\rceil$. However, it is $(\log_{2} {n + 1}) - 1$. So the answer is $O(n + \lceil{\log_{2} n}\rceil- 2)$, not exactly $n + \lceil{\log_{2} n}\rceil - 2$.